# ActiveRecord list custom scopes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I would like to check my ActiveRecord class and see what custom scopes have been applied it

```
class MyRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
    scope :custom_scope_one, ->() { where(id: 4) }
    scope :custom_scope_two, ->() { where(id: 4) }
    scope :custom_scope_three, ->() { where(id: 4) }
end
```

So I run a method like `MyRecord.custom_scopes` and it should return `[:custom_scope_one, :custom_scope_two, :custom_scope_three]`

Is their a built-in way to do this in rails 5? Or how can I do this programmatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`ActiveRecord::Scoping::Named::ClassMethods#scope`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/143991e3e5ffda1dad55b025ce5134c56dfc0029/activerecord/lib/active_record/scoping/named.rb#L155) DSL helper just creates a new method, it does not store the scope name anywhere, so no, it’s not possible out of the box.

OTOH, one might easily provide such a functionality:

```
ActiveRecord::Scoping::Named::ClassMethods.prepend(Module.new do
  def scope(name, body, &block)
    (@__scopes__ ||= []) << name
    super
  end
end)
```

and then the instance variable on your class would be defined:

```
MyRecord.instance_variable_get(:@__scopes__)
#⇒ [:custom_scope_one, :custom_scope_two, :custom_scope_three]
```

You might also declare an accessor for this instance variable or whatever.

*NB* the code above is not tested, I only proved it looks ok.

Comment: But since ["Using a class method is the preferred way to accept arguments for scopes."](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#passing-in-arguments) and there's no sane way to detect if a class method is actually a scope, this won't really work.

Comment: @muistooshort this would work for the example explicitly stated in the original question: any scope declared with `scope` DSL would be successfully reported.